# Date Filter on elastic search

Tags: date, search, range, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a Range Filter on elastic search using the following syntax:

```
{
"size": 100,
"filter": {
"and": {
  "filters": [
    {
      "range": {
        "listingDate": {
          "gt": "15/07/2017 16:08:53"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

The data format is:

```
"listingDate": "07/07/2015 09:30:00",
```

However regardless of the filter properties the same incorrect results are being returned by elastic search.  I have tried adding the following format:

```
"format": "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

but I get the same incorrect results.

A fuller example is:

```
{
"size": 100,
"sort": [
{
  "listingDate": {
    "order": "asc"
  }
}
],
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "Event"
      }
    },
    {
      "range": {
        "listingDate": {
          "gte": "15/07/2015 16:08:53"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "range": {
        "endDate": {
          "gte": "15/07/2015 16:08:53"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
},
"filter": {
"and": {
  "filters": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "departments": [
          "2393"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In JSON documents, dates are represented as strings. Elasticsearch uses a set of preconfigured formats to recognize and parse these strings into a long value representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch in UTC. It might be possible that your date field might not be listed in the set of preconfigured ES date [formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html).

Formatted dates will be parsed using the format specified on the date field by default, but it can be overridden by passing the format parameter to the range query.

```
{
    "range" : {
        "listingDate" : {
            "gte": "07/07/2015 09:30:00",
            "format": "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let suppose "arr" argument have a date range e.g. ["2019-07-10","2019-07-11"]

```
let start_date_query;
let range=[];
if ( arr.date_from ){

    if(arr.date_from[1]){

        range.push({

            "range":{
                "start_date":{ "gte":arr.date_from[0] }
           } 
        });

        range.push({

            "range":{
                "end_date":{ "lte": arr.date_from[1] }
           } 
        });

        start_date_query = {

                "query": {
                  "constant_score": {
                     "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                    "must":range
                }
            }
            }

        };

    }
 } 
}
```